# FileNotFoundError when creating a .exe with PyInstaller while using multiprocess and pandas

Tags: python, excel, multiprocessing, pyinstaller

So I'm working with multiprocessing and to make things more convenient I make my .py script create 2 excel files that are stored in a folder called data.

The problem is that when I create an executable (.exe, I use Windows) using pyinstaller it throws the `FileNotFoundError`. I've seen this issue discussed before but none of the methods worked for me.

My python scripts consist of 1 main script called `test2.py` which calls the `bug_installer.py` module to create some random excels. The `bug_installer.py` module first creates a folder in case there is none and then proceeds to create the excels.

Here's the code:

`bug_installer.py`

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

import pandas as pd
import random as r
from time import sleep
from shutil import copyfile

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            os.mkdir("data")

        except FileExistsError:
            pass
        
        n = 10
        n_dict = {}
        ran = []
        for _ in range(n):
            ran.append(r.choice(list(range(n))))
            
        n_dict["N number"] = ran
        df = pd.DataFrame(n_dict)
        
        og = "df_original.xlsx" 
        ph = "df_placeholder.xlsx"
        
        og_path = os.getcwd()+"\\data\\"+og
        ph_path = os.getcwd()+"\\data\\"+ph
        
        df.to_excel(og_path, index = False)
        copyfile(og_path, ph_path)


        sleep(3)
```

And the `test2.py` module:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

import multiprocessing as mp
import bug_installer as bug
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Process(target=bug.main, args=())
    p.start()
    sleep(3)
    while True:
        df = pd.read_excel("data\\df_placeholder.xlsx")
        print(df)
        sleep(1)
```

Here's the error message:
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the _full_ error message into your question so we don’t have to guess which line the error occurs at.

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that, sorry!

Comment: Are you using `--onefile`?